# How to add navigator to jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I wrote my own slider, it is very simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $('#sliders .slidermain:first').removeClass('hide');
        slider();
    });

    function slider() {
        $('#sliders .slidermain').css({ opacity: 0.0 });
        $('#sliders .slidermain:first').css({ opacity: 1.0 });
        setInterval('show()',7000);
    }

    function show() {
        var current;
        if(#sliders .slidermain.show) {
            current = $('#sliders .slidermain.show');
        }
        else {
            current = $('#sliders .slidermain:first'));
        }

        var next;
        if (current.next().length) {
            next = current.next('#sliders .slidermain');
        }
        else {
            next = $('#sliders .slidermain:first');
        }

        next.css({opacity: 0.0})
            .removeClass('hide')
            .addClass('show')
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

        current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
            .removeClass('show')
            .addClass('hide');
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to add to this slider `nagiator`. For example: If I click an `li` with `rel=1`, I want to make the `div` with `rel=1` appear. I already wrote this:

```
var clicked;
$("#sliders #navi li").click(function()  {
    clicked = $(this).attr('rel')
},
function() {
    next = $("#sliders .slidermain [rel=clicked]");
});
```

But it doesn't work. Could You give me some advices?

Here is a jsFiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/3wAHQ/2/

Comment: You didn't post enough code (html, css)  Perhaps you could make a jsFiddle.

Comment: The link to the page, where I use it: http://wcy9.pl/klienci/mazury/

Comment: I see no sliders on that page.

Comment: @Mat It's much easier to work with if you put it in a fiddle .

Comment: There is it: http://jsfiddle.net/3wAHQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for, is a simple jQuery plugin:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/

It does all that you are asking with the 'navigator' I believe.
A demo is here of [one example](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/index3.php)

Comment: Make sure to test it in all browsers then that you would like to support :P